# How to change error message of model in rails3 on attach file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to change the error message

My Model code is:

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :key_skills, :resume_category, :about_myself, :year_experience, :month_experience, :current_salary, :education_details, :jobs_preference, :resume_title,:avatar,:avatar_file_name,:avatar_content_type

    has_attached_file :avatar,
        :storage => :dropbox,
        :dropbox_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/dropbox.yml",
        :dropbox_options => {
        :unique_filename => true
    }

    validates_format_of :avatar_file_name, :with => %r{\.(docx|doc|pdf)$}i,:message => "Accept only doc and pdf"
```

But Error message is displaying on submit form is : "Avatar file name Accept only doc and pdf"

I need error message: "Accept only doc and pdf"

Comment: See this link: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: Please explain how to do it. I am checking error message in view by <% @resume.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `:"errors.format"` in your locale file, to `format: %{message}`.
Doing this, for each message of any model, only the message will be printed out.

Optionally, you can use something like this: `@resume.errors[:avatar_file_name][0]` the 0 index is because you have only that validations (for now).

However, the best solution to this problem maybe is this:

```
<% @resume.errors.each do |attr, msg|
     msg = @resume.errors.full_message(attr, msg) unless attr == :avatar_file_name %>
```